# How to identify the number of times a character is repeated in a label in C# win forms

Tags: c#, sql, string, if-statement, iteration

I have a button that when clicked pushes(adds) text into a label in C# win form.
Now I need to identify the certain number of times a character in the text in the label is repeated, for example how many times the character "a" is repeated. And after identifying this I plan on having a different action perform when another button is pressed.

Below I will include some of the code I have wrote to give an idea on how I want my app to work.

```
//button that adds text to the label
private void btnLeave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtMembertype.Text == "Level A" && borrow_count > 3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You can only borrow three books at a time", "SyscoTech", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            lblBorrowings.Text = "Books borrowed - ";
        }

        else if (txtMembertype.Text == "Level B" && borrow_count > 2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You can only borrow two books at a time", "SyscoTech", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            lblBorrowings.Text = "Books borrowed - ";
        }
//another button which does the same thing as above
private void btnBorrowedBk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblBorrowings.Text = lblBorrowings.Text + "\n\t " + cmbBooks.Text + "";
        cmbBooks.Text = "";
        borrow_count = borrow_count + 1;
    }

//I plan on having an if-else like below
if (txtMembertype.Text == "Level A" && label.text == "a" > 3 [if a is repeated 3 times])
        {
            // do this
        }

        else if (txtMembertype.Text == "Level B" && label.text == "a" > 2 [if a is repeated two times])
        {
            // do this
        }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With linq you can use the Count extension method:

```
label.text.Count(c=> c == 'a') > 3
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: how do I use this in C#? Is it by a method or something else because right now the text is just underlined in red when I type it. (P.S. I am new to programming) By the way, I did add using.system.linq and the line is still underlined in red.

Comment: I assumed that `label` is a type with the `text` property

Comment: Nevermind i figured out what was wrong. It was highlighted in red because I was typing it outisde the object. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works and you just saved me from a massive headache. Again Thank you.

Comment: It's `.Text` not `.text`. Capitalisation is important.